# Run only parts of shell script with arguments

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

so I've written a shell script that executes commands in sequence. However, it's gotten a little big and there's 3 distinct parts of the code that I need to compartmentalize. I'm new to shell scripts, so what is a good way to put these 3 sections of code into functions(?) that I can call with arguments on the command line to either skip over, or include them in the shell script run?

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I should have posted some example code, so lets say these are the 3 sections, how would I pass arguments in the command line while running the shell script that will do the one of these depending on what I pass. Would also be beneficial if it's the other way too, like skipping the 1st step:

```
pip install -r ./docker/requirements.txt

ZIP_FILE=spark.zip
zip -r $ZIP_FILE file.py

S3_BUCKET_PATH=$S3_BUCKET_PATH
aws s3 cp $ZIP_FILE $S3_BUCKET_PATH/lib/
```

Comment: Put  each section into a function, then your code can do things like `if something; then section1 "$@"; fi`

Comment: it's hard to be more specific if you don't actually post an example of the script and explain how you want to run each section.

Comment: It might be more appropriate to post your complete script to [codereview.se], and ask for advice on how to modularize it.

Comment: **Bash is not suitable for big scripts.** It has only rudimentary data types, no exception handling, there's a massive amount of state to take into account at all times, and it's really difficult to test properly (that is, automatically and comprehensively).

Comment: Put an example in the main question, hopefully that helps with being more specific @Barmar

Comment: How do the command line arguments relate to which sections should run?

Comment: So let's say the 1st line is a section, 2/3 is a section and then last 2 lines are a section. How would I run only the 1st line? so on an so forth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can abstract the segments of your code into functions, then trigger which functions should be run with command line arguments. In the example below, you can run the script with, e.g. `./script.sh --install-requirements --aws-copy`, or equivalently `./script.sh -i -a`.

If you prefer, `case` statements (similar to `switch` in C/C++) can be used instead of the multiple `if`s below, see resources at the bottom for more details.

If you would like to use command line arguments inside of the functions, you can forward them with `$@`, like this: `InstallRequirements "$@"`. You can also pass any other arguments, like this: `InstallRequirements arg1 arg2`, the function will see them the same way a script sees command line arguments.

Also note it's almost always better to enclose variables in double quotes: `rm -rf "$filename"` instead of `rm -rf $filename`. The `rm` without the quotes is very dangerous if the filename contains spaces.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function InstallRequirements {
  pip install -r ./docker/requirements.txt
}

function ZipFile {
  ZIP_FILE=spark.zip
  zip -r "$ZIP_FILE" file.py
}

function AwsCopy {
  S3_BUCKET_PATH=$S3_BUCKET_PATH
  aws s3 cp "$ZIP_FILE" "$S3_BUCKET_PATH/lib/"
}

###

for arg in "$@"; do
  if [[ "$arg" = -i ]] || [[ "$arg" = --install-requirements ]]; then
    ARG_INSTALL_REQUIREMENTS=true
  fi
  if [[ "$arg" = -z ]] || [[ "$arg" = --zip-file ]]; then
    ARG_ZIP_FILE=true
  fi
  if [[ "$arg" = -a ]] || [[ "$arg" = --aws-copy ]]; then
    ARG_AWS_COPY=true
  fi
done

###

if [[ "$ARG_INSTALL_REQUIREMENTS" = true ]]; then
  InstallRequirements
fi

if [[ "$ARG_ZIP_FILE" = true ]]; then
  ZipFile
fi

if [[ "$ARG_AWS_COPY" = true ]]; then
  AwsCopy
fi
```

---

## Resources:

- [Linuxize: Bash Functions](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/)
- [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: Pass arguments to function exactly as-is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78478/357963)
- [Bash Guide for Beginners: 7.3. Using case statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html)
- [Nick Janetakis: Here's Why You Should Quote Your Variables in Bash](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/here-is-why-you-should-quote-your-variables-in-bash)